# & symbol problem in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

my current url is

```
categories_name.php?cname=at&t
```

rewritten url like this.

```
carriers/at&t
```

this is htaccess url.

```
RewriteRule ^carriers/(.*)$ categories_name.php?cname=$1 [L]
```

above url is working for all like

```
categories_name.php?cname=all-tel
```

when variable(at&t) has '&' symbol then problem occuring. so how to write htaccess url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` is a separator between different arguments in the querystring. `at&t` must therefore be urlencoded like this: `at%26t`
otherwise PHP will see it as if you had two arguments: `cname` and `t`

Answer (score 3):

Try it with the [*B* flag for backreference escaping](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags):

```
RewriteRule ^carriers/(.*)$ categories_name.php?cname=$1 [L,B]
```

Comment: occuring '500 Internal Server Error' when i put B flag